# Sencha Chart Rendering issue in Mobile Devices

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

Hello i am using sencha touch for charts there is a issue i am facing when i set 
  showInLegend: false, and 
 legend: {
          position: 'right'
         },
nothing is rendering in mobile devices but in my web browser its working perfect .i have tested in all kind of platforms like ios , android i am using pie charts

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you set showInLegend: false, if I do so it's not rendering as well that's why it's set to true in all cases for my charts. However the legend is not shown in the browser as well but there still remains the container where the legend would be.

Comment: Thanks for replying . Now thing is I am rendering my charts with dynamic data and some properties are user given like chart type ,legend position , showInlegend so if any user don't want to show legends he can pass 'false' to showInlegend property at the time of chart rendering .Is there any way for this type of use case.BTW  which browser u r testing .And i didnt get what u mean to say by this "there still remains the container where the legend would be." thanks again Plz  do rply